# how to set random fake geolocation in selenium python with spasific country

Tags: python, selenium, random, geolocation, faker

I'm try to add a random fake `geolocation` from valid country like USA or UK

maybe this can help `pip install geopy` ?

Comment: Use a proxy or run Selenium on google colab, which uses a US ip address

Comment: already use proxy from same country that why i need to use multi location than the proxy give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To geolocate a query to an address and coordinates:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)

Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(40.7410861, -73.9896297241625)

print(location.raw)
{'place_id': '9167009604', 'type': 'attraction', ...}
```

To find the address corresponding to a set of coordinates:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")

location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")

print(location.address)
Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(52.5094982, 13.3765983)

print(location.raw)
{'place_id': '654513', 'osm_type': 'node', ...}
```

https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/